# Grant write permissions to extenal sd card using adb

Tags: android, file, permissions, adb, television

I need some help with granting write permissions to external sd card on an Android TV box (Xiaomi Mi Box).
I plugged a micro SD card using a USB adapter and I can access the files and read them without any problem. I can even write to an app specific folder located at Android\data\app package name.
However, When I try to write files to the root directory of the sd card I'm asked to Grant permission to the app. On a normal Android phone a different app bulit in inside of Android will be opened, where there I will select the sd card and then and give the app a permissions for writing to it. However, this app doesn't exists on the Mi Box.
I side loaded the app to the streamer (it's called my files),and it was installed successfully, but it didn't show me the sd card I plugged in what so ever, so I couldn't give the app a write permissions.
So my question is: is there an alternative way to grant an app a write permissions to an extenal SD card? Maybe through adb? 
If someone knows about any solution it would be really helpful.
If your solution doesn't involve rooting it would be wonderful.
Thank you and have a great day!